# Computing mean and standard deviation of a set of time series data

Tags: time-series, mean, standard-deviation

Consider a set of $M$ time series described by $D = \{d^1,\ldots,d^M\}$ where each $d^i$ is a time series of the same length, say $N$.

I want to create a plot with the mean time series and the standard deviation. What I initially thought was to compute the mean and standard deviation of the collection of points **at each time step** $n=1,\ldots, N$ then just plot that. But this *point-wise* approach seems like an overly naive approach for time-series data: the "mean" trajectory formed this way certainly isn't the average trajectory found in $D$ (similarly when computing the standard deviation).

I am wondering if there is a better approach that computes the mean and standard deviation *trajectory-wise* rather than in the above described point-wise way.

I hope I'm making myself clear.

Comment: For the mean, in what sense would it not be "the average trajectory found in $D$"?  For the standard deviation (or variance), it depends on what you are trying to describe with your statistic.

Comment: This is what I’ve been wrestling with. When computing the mean of a finite set of numbers $X$ in the space $[0,1]$ there’s of course no reason that the mean of $X$ is in $X$. I suppose the same logic holds for a set of trajectories? But when it comes to the standard deviation we need some notion of distance between the elements (to say that this many trajectories are within one standard deviation of the mean) so the logic doesn’t directly carry over.